# How to get a button to grow vertically using Auto Layout in iOS7?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, button, layout, autolayout

Using IB and Auto Layout I would like to have a button that grows in size vertically when the title is long.

I've added top, leading and trailing constraint to the button and a Line break of Word wrap. Then I assign a long title in viewDidLoad. But the resulting button doesn't fit the content. What am I missing here?

[image: IB]

[image: Simulator]

[image: Button]

[image: Constraints]

Trying to overcome the lack of automated update of the height:

```
CGFloat width = 280;
NSAttributedString *attributedText =
[[NSAttributedString alloc]
 initWithString:self.button.titleLabel.text
 attributes:@
 {NSFontAttributeName: self.button.titleLabel.font}];
CGRect rect = [attributedText boundingRectWithSize:(CGSize){width, CGFLOAT_MAX}
                                          options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin
                                           context:nil];
CGSize size = rect.size;
CGRect buttonRect = self.button.frame;
buttonRect.size.height = size.height;
[self.button setFrame: buttonRect];
```

But the frame of the button is not being updated.....

With the excellent solution provided by rdelmar below I got the following result:

[image]

Comment: Those constraints worked for me. Are you sure you don't have any other constraints?

Comment: Yes - that's the only constraints. If I add a background the button is not growing. The text is visible - but not within the boundary of the button. Do you see the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the title over the image (not beside) you need to use backgroundImage:forState:. As far as I can tell from experimenting with this, you can't get the image to expand with the title in an automatic way. If you have no image, then those constraints work to make the title expand vertically.

**After Edit:** I never found any good automatic way to do this, but you can do it by calculating the height of the string, and adjusting the height of the button accordingly. I found the best way to do this was to give the button both a width and height constraint in IB -- this will cause your background image to stretch or shrink to fit that frame. I made a UIButton subclass (changed the class of the the button in IB), and put this code in it:

```
@interface RDButton ()
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSLayoutConstraint *hCon;
@property (strong,nonatomic) NSLayoutConstraint *wCon;
@property (nonatomic) CGFloat startingHeight;
@end

@implementation RDButton

-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        for (NSLayoutConstraint *con in self.constraints) {
            if (con.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeHeight) {
                self.hCon = con;
                self.startingHeight = con.constant;
            }else if (con.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttributeWidth){
                self.wCon = con;
            }
        }
    }
    self.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    self.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    return self;
}

-(void)setTitle:(NSString *)title forState:(UIControlState)state {
    [super setTitle:title forState:state];
    NSStringDrawingContext *ctx = [NSStringDrawingContext new];
    CGSize s = [title boundingRectWithSize:CGSizeMake(self.wCon.constant, CGFLOAT_MAX) options:NSStringDrawingUsesLineFragmentOrigin attributes:@{NSFontAttributeName:self.titleLabel.font} context:ctx].size;
    self.hCon.constant = fmax (s.height, self.startingHeight - 5) + 5; // the +5 gives about the same padding as the original button.
}
```

In the view controller where I'm setting the new title, I have this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self.button setTitle:@"A long long long Title" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.jpg"];
    [self.button setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: I must be missing something really basic here. Please see the pictures I've added to the question. The button only reacts to touch in the green background area - hence the button don't seem to grow vertically to me.

Comment: @FEK, yeah, I think that's just the way it works. I messed with this for quite a while, and found out that although the titleLabel of the button grows to the correct size, the size of the button itself does not change (which is why the touch still only works in the green area). As far as I can tell, you haven't missed anything basic.

Comment: Thanks - it has been driving me crazy for a while. Is there no way I can change this? The problem is that I have additional buttons - and their text overlaps the other buttons - as the constraints are only adjusting according to the green area....

Comment: @FEK, I don't know of any easy way. I think you need to figure out the height of the titleLabel, then change the size of the button to match that. I tried everything I could think of, and couldn't get it to update automatically. Things like sizeToFit, which seems like it should work, didn't

Comment: Thanks. I've found a way to calculate the height. But setting the frame on the button doesn't work. Please see the addition to the question.

Comment: @FEK, you shouldn't set frames if you're using auto layout (you should adjust constraints, so you would probably need a height constraint to do it this way).

Comment: Excellent - thanks. I'll try it out - probably in the weekend. I'll return and accept your answer as a solution, if it's working for me as well.

Comment: Couldn't wait - just had to try this out. With a few minor tweaks it's working perfectly. In the RDButton.h I have: @interface RDButton : UIButton. And in the self.hCon.constant calculation I made it +25. Thank you so much - as stated earlier this was driving me crazy and your solution is appreciated very much!